# Unity3d: Why texture quality is not as good when compared to Android studio VR project?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

[image]I am making a photo gallery cardboard app in Unity, with hundreds of textures(3328X1664 res). Whatever resolution or compression technique I use, the textures looks very blurry. I have tried making them cube map and eventually made skybox out of these, I have kept these in 2d and created a custom shader which would wrap those in an inverted sphere with a Camera inside it, But still, I did not get the same texture quality which I have achieved in a simple VR project developed in Android Studio(Using same quality pictures)

I want to know if there's something I could do without hampering the performance of the app.

I did try the below method-

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.VR;

public class Renderexample : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float m_RenderScale = 2f; //The render scale. Higher 
    numbers = better quality, but trades performance

    void Start()
    {
    VRSettings.renderScale = m_RenderScale;
    }
}
```

But this does not help with anything, rather frame rate reduces drastically and makes me nauseous.

Really require your help folks!
Please help!

Update: Adding a screenshot of the settings.

Comment: Have you disabled mipmaps ?

Comment: Yes, I have unticked 'Generate Mipmap' option and changed the filter mode to point. @Hellium updated the question with the texture settings as well.

Comment: Have you also tried not overriding the settings for _Android_ but only setting them inside the _Default_ tab with following values: `Max Size : 4096` and `Compression : None` (remember to un-tick `Override for Android)`)? This should be the equivalent of the old `TrueColor` setting.

Comment: tried this method,  but the quality of the images remains the same. Also, size of the images increases to 72 MB. Which is quite huge.